# Efecto de Scroll no funciona jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

Aquí esta El codigo de jQuery, es lo ultimo.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí esta el Html[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí esta donde quiero que se mueva[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero des afortunadamente no hace nada, alguien me ayuda por favor? Gracias :D

Answer (score 0):

Esta forma funciona bastante bien:

**JS:**

```
   $(function(){

         $('a[href*=#]').click(function() {

         if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')
             && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

                 var $target = $(this.hash);

                 $target = $target.length && $target || $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');

                 if ($target.length) {

                     var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;

                     $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000);

                     return false;

                }

           }

       });
```

**HTML:**

Enlace que te llevará al sitio:

```
<a id="up" href="#to_up"> UP </a>
```

Y esto lo pones en el sitio donde quieres que te lleve:

```
<a name="to_up"></a>
```

Comment: Gracias lo voy a probar